# How to execute function when anchor tag was opened?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to send a post request (with a payload) to my server when a user opens a link in my React app.

My current approach is to use the `onClick` and `onAuxClick` callbacks, and then filter out right-clicks (because those don't directly open links).

```
<a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" 
onClick={onLinkClicked} onAuxClick={onLinkClicked}>
    <FaExternalLinkAlt className={styles.headerButton} />
</a>
```

```
function onLinkClicked(event: MouseEvent) {
    if ([0,1].includes(event.button)) {
        alert('track click')
    }
}
```

However, **right clicks followed by opening the link via the context menu are also ignored.**

Another option seems to be to use the [ping](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/html-defines-a-ping-attribute-on-anchor-elements-links/#:%7E:text=The%20anchor%20element%27s%20ping%20attribute,users%20interact%20with%20your%20site.) callback. However, there are two problems with this: Ping doesn't seem to contain a payload/body, which I need. And browser support seems to be flaky.

**How can I reliably track link clicks without false positives and without ignoring opening the link via the context menu (and any other ways of opening a link)?**

Comment: There are no reliable ways to track the open links since it is not a javascript feature but a browser one, with anchor elements serving just as instructions for browser and not actual user code.

Comment: @syduki Thank you. What would be the best alternative in your opinion? Using on(Aux)Click like I do?

Comment: There are no "best alternatives" as the what you are doing now is pretty much the only thing that can be done

Answer (score 1):

You can force the link to be opened even if the user clicks the wrong button and  with that you ensure the actual click count

### Edit 1:

For some reason, the contextmenu event fires twice so I advise that you handle that issue I tried removing the event propagation and investigating on it and found nothing

```js
const a  = document.querySelector('a');

//              left,     right,         middle      Clicks
const events = ['click', 'contextmenu', 'auxclick'] // You can add more events if you feel the need to

const cb = (clickType, elem) => {
  console.log(clickType);
  console.log(elem.href);
  
  // Open link and do the post request here
}


events.forEach(eve => {
  a.addEventListener(eve, (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      cb(e.which, a);

  })

})
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">click</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. This would open the link as soon as the user clicks the right mouse button? It's an interesting approach but I'm not sure that I want to modify the expected behavior like this.

Comment: There is no guaranteed way  to know if the user actually opened the other website other than ensuring that  the website opens itself or if you can collect analytics from the other website using URL params

Comment: You can collect analytics from the other website by sending a URL param /?myKey="userGeneratedID"&origin="MyWebsite"    and count how many times the user visited the other website through the origin and myKey  params

Comment: but can I track this info on MY website (not the link target)?

Comment: the other website should give you access to your analytics

Comment: I don't know what that means. How can they give me access to MY analytics? What do you mean by "my analytics"?

Comment: the other website can have analytics to confirm that some requests came from your website they keep track of users coming in from your website and how many times they visit etc. they also should expose an API  for you to access your data/ analtyics

Comment: Ok, I get it. That's not suitable for my use case the links can be from any website.

Comment: then there is no way to ensure that the user opened the website other than ensuring he goes to it on any click

Comment: You can just record the clicks and make a statistical semi-accurate estimate of the number of visits based on the type of click

Comment: I'm looking to show a history of visited links in my app, not statistics.